# toast in android studio is not showing message properly?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have used it and when i am running the emulator in toast message it is only showing (The Name is). How to solve it ??

```
val name = textInput.editableText.toString()
createButton.setOnClickListener{
    Toast.makeText(this, "The name is$name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the variable value is already obtained when the click happens

```
createButton.setOnClickListener{
    val name = textInput.editableText.toString()
    Toast.makeText(this, "The name is$name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

So in your code

```
val name = textInput.editableText.toString() //this value doesn't get updated when the click happens
createButton.setOnClickListener{
    //what happen in decompiled code here is that name enters as a final copy of the name above
    Toast.makeText(this, "The name is$name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //here the name variable is not updated with the latest text because there is nothing make the val value change
}
```

When you declare

```
val foo = editText.text.toStringt()
```

That declaration doesn't get updated automatically when the `editText` text change, because the `val foo` is no holding an observable from the edit text, got the value on that moment and that is the end of it. Same here:

```
checkBox.isChecked = true
val bar = checkBox.isCHecked //bar is true
checkBox.isChecked = false
println(bar)//this is still true
```

A variable is a space in memory that is allocated for that value, after it was allocated, then it won't change because the source change. But things can be mutated:

```
class Dog(var name: String)
val dog = Dog("foo")
println(dog.name) //here is foo
dog.name = "bar
println(dog.name) //here is bar
```

Because the variable `dog` is referencing an object wich internal properties changed.

What you are missing is: inmutability and observables. Check for those concepts.